# Avoid AJAX from console

Tags: javascript, ajax, security, jquery, xmlhttprequest

Let's say I have several `ajax` request in my web-application. 
This request requires `id`'s from **user** and from stuff I'm sending to the *server* . 
Unluckily this `id`'s are visible to users who inspect the code and so they , with a little bit of knowledge, can send `ajax` request through the *developer console* of the browser. 
How can I avoid this kind of situation?

Comment: You can't, why do you need to? You should never depend on client-side processing for security, since it can always be observed and overridden by the user.

Comment: Uhm.. Ok but there is a way to avoid this situation with an authorization code , like Twitter or Facebook API does?

Comment: Encrypt the id's.  Experienced users will still be able to emulate requests, but at least they won't be able to guess the other user's id.

Comment: how can I do this once the javascript has been written?